# Gradle 3.3 and latest build tools

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle

Recently I've upgraded Android Studio to version 2.3 and my projects to latest build tools (>=25) and Gradle 3.3. It compiles fine in AS, however every project throws an error when compiled on my Jenkins machine.

Depending on the project, error occurs on various tasks, but it's always aapt related

> Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 139

It recreates both with 25.0.0. and 25.0.2. I've compared sdk on my jenkins machine with sdk I have local and both have all the required components - correct version of build-tools, platform-tools, platforms, m2repositories and tools.

Compilation log isn't much helpful as it doesn't provide any info that could help narrow the problem.

Anyone struggled with similar issues or have any idea how to fix it?

Cheers,

Comment: Guess you need to find out the reason, try to enable stacktraces for the gradle build on Jenkins. Can you reproduce the problem when building from the command line on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

> Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 139

When the JVM runs, exit codes up to 127 are reserved for errors with the JVM itself, so when it runs an external process that fails, it adds 128 to the exit code.  In this case, 139 minus 128 is 11, meaning that `aapt` exited with signal 11 (SIGSEGV), which is a segmentation fault crash.

So it sounds like a problem with `aapt` itself.  Can you manually run `aapt` on the Jenkins build machine to see what happens, or if it gives any more information?

It may be worth reporting this on [b.android.com](http://b.android.com/) along with the OS, version, and CPU architecture you're running on.